# How do I use the . properly with sql?

Tags: sql

I am new to sql and have a question about joining 2 tables. Why is there a `.` in between `customers.custnum` in this example. What is its significance and what does it do?

Ex.

```
Select 
    customers.custnum, state, qty
From 
    customers 
Inner join 
    sales On customers.custnum = sales.custnum
```

Comment: In your particular query both columns `customers.custnum` and `sales.custnum` always have the same value because of the join predicate. Sometimes, however, columns with the same name (from different tables) may end up having totally different values, and you want to make sure you are selecting the right one. The prefix is then, necessary.

Comment: @marc_s: that's actually one of the most basic syntax rules in the SQL standard. It references the column of a table and is absolutely identical across all DBMS products

Answer (score 2):

The `.` is to specify a column of a table.
Let's use your customer table; we could do:

```sql
SELECT c.custnum, c.state, c.qty FROM customers as c INNER JOIN 
    sales as s ON c.custnum = s.custnum
```

You don't really need the `.` unless two tables have columns with the same name.

Comment: I would recommend to prepend each column with the table name (preferrable its alias) on every query that uses more than one table. +1 anyway

Comment: Wouldn't that become redundant and bloated in bigger databases though? Also the more complexity and abbreviations you add, the more confusing it can become. I'd personally recommend against it (speaking from experience).

Comment: @Levasseur-Sp, I would side with TheImpaler on adding aliases especially for anyone following after a person no longer with a company and trying to pick up pieces.  Aliases accurate vs just a, b, c, d can be vague except "c" for customers.  But something like "o" for "Orders" or "oDtl" for OrderDetails.  I have seen VeryLongTableNames in posts out here and that could get painful to follow and see.

Comment: I feel embarrassed because I just realized what he meant... I thought he was saying to change the column names to 'table_column' as to never have to use the '.' . Now that I get it, I agree with him too!

Answer (score 1):

In the below query, there are two tables being referred. One is CUSTOMERS another is STATE. Since both has same column CUSTNUM, we need a way to tell the database which CUSTNUM are we referring to. Same as there may be many Bob's, if so their last name is used for disambiguation.

I would consider the below style as more clearer. That's opinionated.

```
Select 
    cust.custnum, cust.state, s.qty 
From 
    customers cust -- use alias for meaningful referencing, you may be self-joining, during that time you can use cust1, cust2 as aliases.
Inner join 
    sales as s On cust.custnum = s.custnum
```

Comment: I would recommend to prepend each column with the table name (preferrable its alias) on every query that uses more than one table. +1

Answer (score -2):

Think of it as a way to categorize the hierarchical nature of the database. Within a DB, there are tables, and within tables there are columns. It's just a way of keeping track, especially if you are working with multiple tables that may have the same column name.

For example, a table called Sales and a table called Customers might both have a column called Date. You may be writing a query where you only want the date from the Sales table, so you would specify that by writing:

`Select *
From Sales
inner join Customers on Sales.ID = Customers.ID
where Sales.Date = '1/1/2019'`